# Will I receive a 1099-B if I bought stocks but didn't sell?

Tags: united-states, taxes

This is the first year I've bought stocks independently through a broker.

Do I need to wait for, or will I even receive a 1099-B if I only bought stocks last year but did not sell?

The deadline for brokerages is February 15th.

I would like to file my taxes now, but I'm unsure if I need to wait for a 1099-B that may or may not come.

Comment: Did any of those stocks distribute dividends?  Did you own any funds that were managed by others who may have bought and sold stocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A purchase of a stock is not a taxable event. No 1099 to worry about.

Welcome to Money.SE